# require bootstrap and jquery in aurelia app

Tags: aurelia, jspm

I'm new to Aurelia, so I'm not really sure how this should work. I created a new Aurelia project and also installed `bootstrap` simply by doing `jspm install bootstrap`. I saw in console that this also pulled in `jquery 3.0.0`.

Now my question is, how do I use `bootstrap.css`, `bootstrap.js` and `jquery.js` in my project?

First attempt:

In `app.html` I tried to do thhe following:

```
<require from="bootstrap"></require>
```

I tried that because I have the following line in my `config.js`:

```
map: {
    ...
    "bootstrap": "github:twbs/bootstrap@3.3.6",
    ...
}
```

This sort of works in the sense that it loads `bootstrap.js`, but then gives an error in browser that it's missing `jquery.js`. So it's not automatically loading jquery for me. ***Is this normal?***

Second attempt:

I changed my `require` to this in `app.html`:

```
<require from="jquery/dist/jquery.js"></require>
<require from="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css"></require>
<require from="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></require>
```

I'm not sure how it knows where to look for the `bootstrap.js` and `bootstrap.css` file, since they are located in: `jspm_packages/github/twbs/bootstrap@3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css` etc. But it knows how to find the bootstrap files. But ***not*** the jquery file.

I have this in my `config.js` for jquery:

```
map: {
    ...
    "github:twbs/bootstrap@3.3.6": {
      "jquery": "npm:jquery@3.0.0"
    },
    ....
}
```

So basically my question is, how should this work? Should `require` autoload all the necessary files when I `<require from="bootstrap">`. Or should I still load them as individual files? If so, how do I then load jquery in this case?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `require` element is for pulling in Aurelia components, html templates (which are Aurelia components), or css files. It isn't for loading javascript files.

The Aurelia skeleton shows how to load Bootstrap in its `main.js` file:

```
import 'bootstrap';
```

is the first line in the file. This will initialize Bootstrap's javascript code.

In `app.html` a `require` element is used to load Bootstrap's css:

```
<require from="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css"></require>
```

Importing jQuery in to a file is pretty simple as well:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
```

Then you can use the `$` function however you would like.

Comment: It can't find `jquery` when I import it like you said. Eventhough there is a jquery file located at: `jspm_packages/npm/jquery@3.0.0/dist/jquery.js`.

Comment: You probably ran `jspm install bootstrap`, but you'll need to also run `jspm install jquery` to be able to import `jquery` like I'm doing above.

Comment: Just ran `jspm install jquery`. Now it's able to load `jquery.js`. But, it still complains that `bootstrap` requires the `jQuery` plugin. I have `import $ from  'jquery'` first, then `import 'bootstrap`. Could this then maybe be a bug or am I still missing something?

Comment: I would recommend comparing your code to the aurelia esnext skeleton located here: https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-navigation/tree/master/skeleton-esnext

Comment: `import 'bootstrap';`

`import 'jquery';`

in app.js worked for me! Project built using aurelia cli.

Added entries for jquery and bootstrap in "aurelia.json" as described in [contact manager tutorial](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/framework/latest/contact-manager-tutorial)

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem then installed latest node and npm, and then from the tutorial page on the aurelia site:-

To get Bootstrap setup, we begin by installing the library itself with NPM. Execute the following on the command line to do this:

```
npm install bootstrap --save
```

Next, because Bootstrap uses jQuery, we want to install jQuery as well, like this:

```
npm install jquery@^2.2.4 --save
```

then restarted the app as packages were updated and ran it again ... FIXED!

Answer (score 0):

after adding 
import 'bootstrap';
in main.js, you may need to stop the app (Ctrl + c) and run it again with
au run --watch
to make it work.